# How to have the same program without having a attribute class which is here the int private counter

Tags: java, class, javafx, attributes

I want to get the same effect and the same code but without using any class attribute, or any static attribute.

The class attribute here is the int private counter I want to remove that and use something else which give me the same effect

```
public class main extends Application{
    
    private int counter=0; 

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    launch(args);

    }
    
     public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    primaryStage.setTitle("add and sub");
     
     Button b = new Button("+");
     Button b2 = new Button("-");
     
     GridPane root = new GridPane();
     Label l = new Label("0");
     root.add(b, 0, 0);
     root.add(l, 0, 1);
     root.add(b2, 0, 2);
     b.setOnAction(e ->
     {
     counter++;
     l.setText(""+counter);
     });
     b2.setOnAction(e ->
     {
     counter--;
     l.setText(""+counter);
     });

     Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 100);
     primaryStage.setScene(scene);
     
     primaryStage.show();   
}
```

Comment: you seem to be learning local fields :) Best to re-read your course book on that chapter (hint: at the end of day it's a simple move from the body of the class to the body of the method .. with a slight omission)

Comment: .. ahh .. there's twirk that I didn't see at first: you are changing the counter in a lambda - so you need to re-read the chapter about rules around lambdas as well :) Which makes your requirement even more contrived

Answer (score 0):

You could read the current value from the label and parse it.

```
Integer counter = Integer.parseInt(l.getText());
counter++;
l.setText(counter.toString());
```

Comment: where do i put that exactly can u further explain ?

Comment: can u maybe further explain where should i add that cause i wanna remove the private int counter and not use any class attribut if you know what i mean

Comment: there is no added value in boxing a plain int into an Integer, is there ;)

Comment: @OP - why? the requirement sounds very artificial, just like a homework assignement. Which is fine to ask about but should put an incentive to you _learning_ the basics :)

Comment: @kleopatra: The boxing was inserted intentionally. The added value is the use of `.toString()` which is a nicer solution than `""+counter`

Answer (score 0):

You Probably want to use the counter for something else, later on or increase it outside of UI input.

The problem with "int" and lambdas is, that lambdas are shortcut representations for "Anonymous classes". in the methodscope the "int increment" will cause trouble, unless you do it static (wich is not recomended) on a other object, or have a object container. 
You can only Use effectivly final objects in Lambdas. reassignment operations of Objects that are initialised outside of the Lambda expression are not allowed.

You could Use a Property Object. You want to increment the counter, and then the incremented Counter should be represented in the View. 
Meaning the label should be changed when the counter changes.
Probably sometimes not a button changes the counter but something you calculate or recieve from a request.

Or you want to update the time or whatever

```java
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
     primaryStage.setTitle("add and sub");

     // this is a way that allows you to Have a Object
     // that is observable and can notify a change to something else
     // it has a value of the Type Integer
     IntegerProperty counter= new SimpleIntegerProperty(0);

     Button b = new Button("+");
     Button b2 = new Button("-");

     GridPane root = new GridPane();
     Label l = new Label("0");
     root.add(b, 0, 0);
     root.add(l, 0, 1);
     root.add(b2, 0, 2);

     // Here do you increment and decrement the counter
     b.setOnAction(e ->
      {
          counter.set(counter.get()+1);

      });
     b2.setOnAction(e ->
      {
          counter.set(counter.get()-1);
      });


     // Now you want to have the Label uptdated whenever the counter changes
     // you add a listener wich has the the Parameters: the object itself, the old value, 
     //and the new Value.
     // this method will be called whenever the Property changes. Not only if you push a 
     // button. It will always update the Label
     counter.addListener((obj,oldValue,newValue)->{

            outText.setText("" + newValue);

        });

     Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 100);
     primaryStage.setScene(scene);

     primaryStage.show();   
}
```